# Host pagespeed insights on my own server

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

As title, is there any way to host google pagespeed insights on my own server instead of using google api to run a test?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to make that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but with a few caveats.

First off, the [core of PageSpeed is open-source](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/psol), and so are the [browser extensions (Chrome, FF)](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights_extensions), which provide built-in optimization recommendations. Given the projects above, you already have all the necessary code available to run it yourself.

PageSpeed also ships with a har_to_pagespeed tool, which you can use to to generate a list of recommendations. Check out this [blog post from Steve Souders](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/05/01/har-to-page-speed). Link to his [online tool](http://stevesouders.com/flint/index.php?f=cnn.har).

To generate a har file you'll need a separate process / browser driver - there are a few open-source tools available that can do this. Check out phantom.js.

Finally, the above has a small caveat. `har_to_pagespeed` won't give you the exact same results as a browser extension, because the browser extensions analyze the DOM as well and make some recommendations based on that. This data is not available within the HAR format.

Comment: I realized that using har_to_pagespeed is almost useless since lots of useful info can not be grabbed by har files. I am thinking if it is possible to run it with phantomjs.